# Graphical Block Composition Library similar to Quartz Composer in Java

Tags: javascript, user-interface

Is there a library that allows me to manipulate graphical components similar to Quartz Composer "patch editor", preferentially implemented in JavaScript (or anything close enough that can be easily modified)?

[image: Quartz Composer Snapshot]

Comment: I know this is not quite the thing, but the man is a genius:
http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [JSPlumb](http://jsplumb.org/jquery/flowchartConnectorsDemo.html) is a good starting point...

Comment: I agree, but can it be saved locally ?

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in Ames Bielenberg's [Flow](https://github.com/Ames/flow), a node-based visual programming environment.

[image]